# WP not sending correct headers to download a file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP plugin that sends a link to an email to download a file in hidden location. User selects a file, then a token containing the file ID etc. is written to a database, and a link is sent. Upon clicking the link (ex. mysite.com/thank-you/?id=asd687asd68as7d6a8sdd7sd768as7d6, the "thank you" page makes a request to a php function to donload the file.

There's also a dummy "download engine" page with a shortcode [download_page] that initiates the download.

Weird thing is that while this setup works just fine at test environment, and has worked for over a year at production site, it suddenly stopped working: 
  call for DownloadFile() returns 0KB and correct headers at test site, and initiates the download, but 
  returns full HTML file and, of course, no download.

I cannot spot any changes in configuration (both sites run WP 4.2.7). Only difference seems to be the WooCommerce plugin, and Google Analytics snippet included in production site.And that test site runs PHP 5.3 while productiopn site runs 5.6.

I'd be very grateful if somebody had an insight of what's happening.. Why are headers ignored? (There's no "Headers already sent" error.) Why is full HTML of the dummy "download engine" page displayed?

BTW it's an out-of-the-box theme, but I cannot spot no faults in it. But still, maybe.. Where I'm to look for a culprit lines? What could force a page to show full HTML instead of headers sent by php?

Relevant code is such:
(download manager.php):

```
<?php 
  /*
  Plugin Name: Hidden Download Manager
  Description: Bla bla
  */
  include_once('add_meta_boxes.php');
  include_once('mfdm_frontend_functions.php');
  add_action( 'init', 'program_register' );
  add_shortcode( 'download_page', 'downloadFile' );
?>
```

(thank_you.tpl.php)

```
<?php
  /**
  Template Name: Thank You
  */
  $HOST = get_option('mfdm_dbhost');
  $USER = get_option('mfdm_dbuser');
  $PWORD = get_option('mfdm_dbpwd');
  $DB = get_option('mfdm_dbname');
  $connect_db = mysqli_connect($HOST,$USER,$PWORD,$DB) or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($connect_db));
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $id = stripslashes($_GET['id']);
  } else {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
  }
  $result = $connect_db->query("SELECT * FROM 3_downloadkey WHERE uniqueid = '$id'");
  $row = resultToArray($result);
  $redirect = '';
  if (!$row) { 
    // redirect to 'invalid' page
    $redirect = get_option('mfdm_link_invalid_page');
    wp_redirect($redirect);
    exit;
  }
    get_header();
    $plugindir = plugin_dir_url(0).'mouseful_download/';

    // embed the javascript file that makes the AJAX request
    wp_enqueue_script( 'processLink_request', $plugindir . 'mf_downloads.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    // declare the URL to the file that handles the AJAX request (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
    wp_localize_script('processLink_request', 'ProcessLink', array(
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
      'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ProcessLink-post-comment-nonce' ),
      'downloadHiddenPage' => get_option('mfdm_download_hidden_page')
    )
  );
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?=$plugindir;?>mf_downloads.css">


<body onLoad="setTimeout('downloadLink()', 1000)"></body>
<div class="contents about">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col banner">
       <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>        
<div class="row2"><div class="col">
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
</div></div></div>
<?php 
  get_footer(); 
?>
```

(mfdm_frontend_functions.php):

```
<?php
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_downloadLink-submit', 'downloadFile' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_downloadLink-submit', 'downloadFile' );

function downloadFile() {
  $HOST = get_option('mfdm_dbhost');
  $USER = get_option('mfdm_dbuser');
  $PWORD = get_option('mfdm_dbpwd');
  $DB = get_option('mfdm_dbname');
  $id = $_POST['app'];
  $connect_db = mysqli_connect($HOST,$USER,$PWORD,$DB);
  $result = $connect_db->query("SELECT * FROM 3_downloadkey WHERE uniqueid = '$id'");
  $row = resultToArray($result);
  $app_ID = $row[0]['app_ID'];
  ob_start();
  // get app name 
  $base_dir = get_option('mfdm_applications_folder');
  define('BASE_DIR',$base_dir);
  $fname = get_post_meta($app_ID, 'meta_source', true);
  $app_download_name = get_post_meta($app_ID, 'meta_program_name', true);

  $file_path = '';
  $file_path = find_file1(BASE_DIR, $fname, $file_path);
  if (!is_file($file_path)) {
    die("File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name.");
  }
  $fsize = filesize($file_path); 
  $fext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fname,"."),1));
  $mime_types = array(
    'msi' => 'application/x-ole-storage',
    'zip' => 'application/zip',
    'exe' => 'application/x-msdownload',
    'sh' => 'application/x-sh',
    'iso' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'dmg' => 'application/octet-stream',
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
  );
  $mm_type = $mime_types[$fext];
  if ($fd = fopen ($file_path, "r")) {
  $fsize = filesize($file_path);
  $path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
  $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
  header("Content-type: $mm_type");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$app_download_name."\"");
  header("Content-length: $fsize");
  header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly       
  while(ob_POST_level() > 0) {
    @ob_end_clean();
  }
  while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
  }
}
fclose ($fd);
}
?>
```

(mf_downloads.js):

```
function downloadLink() {
  var id = window.location.search.replace("?", "").split("&")[0];
  id = id.split("=")[1];
  var url = ProcessLink.downloadHiddenPage;
  var form = jQuery('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' + '<input type="text" name="app" value="' + id + '" hidden="hidden"/>' + '</form>');
  jQuery('body').append(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'downloadFile' function in 'mfdm_frontend_functions.php' should end with wp_die() in order to return a [proper response](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

```
wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
```

Upload a user-defined php.ini to your webroot containing the following line:

```
default_charset = ""
```

Comment: Very reasonable suggestion. However, even if I put wp_die(); to the very beginning of 'mfdm_frontend_functions.php' downloadFile(), the 'download-engine' page is still called and displayed fully. That's the weird thing: the page shouldn't be displayed should it?

Comment: @Konservin you should add wp_die to the end of your script (below fclose ($fd);).

Comment: @Konservin where's your ajax function?

Comment: Ajax is called by shortcode [download_page], with add_shortcode( 'download_page', 'downloadFile' ); at 'download_manager.php'

PS. I added the wp_die et the end at first, but with no result. Then tried to add it to the beginning (reasoning that then there should be no output at all), but output is still there (the full HTML of 'download-engine' page)

Comment: @Konservin just updated my answer, let me know if it works with the php.ini changes.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to php.ini.. It's on a shared provider.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106152/discussion-between-dontanios-and-konservin).